# find documents by $in in embedded arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have following document

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5461363bdfef7c4800146f4b"),
    "title": "Plant Overview",
    "segments": [
        {
            "tagBindings": [
                {
                    "id" : ObjectId("54ac12f4b4f22ec30153ea83"),
                    "tagType" : "Facility"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : ObjectId("54999a0e899ab5530031535e"),
                    "tagType" : "Facility"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5498189c496623160068831c"),
                    "tagType" : "Facility"
                }
            ],
            "name": "Liberty Lofts - Solar Power Plant",
            "id": ObjectId("54637850dfcbe62000a7eddf")
        }
    ]
 }
```

I want find records where segments.tagBindings.id is equals to some values and does not have any other Id.

I use that query:

```
db.ds_dashboards.find({"segments.tagBindings.id": {$in: [ObjectId("54ac12f4b4f22ec30153ea83"), ObjectId("54999a0e899ab5530031535e")]}})
```

it returns above document.

But I don't need it, because third segments.tagBindings.id is `5498189c496623160068831c` id.

How I should update query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use aggregation and take advantage of the `$setIsSubset` operator. So your query would look something like this:

```
> db.ds_dashboards.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$segments"},
    { "$unwind": "$segments.tagBindings" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "tagBindings" : { "$addToSet": "$segments.tagBindings.id" }
        }
    },
    { "$project": {
        "isValid": {
            "$setIsSubset": [
                "$tagBindings",
                [ObjectId("54ac12f4b4f22ec30153ea83"),
                 ObjectId("54999a0e899ab5530031535e")]
            ]}
        }
    }
]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5461363bdfef7c4800146f4b"), "isValid" : false }
```

The query above, as shown, given your sample document, would return false. This is because, as you say, `ObjectId("5498189c496623160068831c")` is not present in `$tagBindings`. If you modify that array to include the said `ObjectId`, then it will return true.

You can then add a `match` clause to filter out the results were `isValid` is false. This last clause would look something like this: `{ "$match": { "isValid": true } }`.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should use $all for this like;

```
db.ds_dashboards.find({"segments.tagBindings.id": 
{$all:[ObjectId("54ac12f4b4f22ec30153ea83"), ObjectId("54999a0e899ab5530031535e")]}})
```

You can also combine it with $size operator for exact match like;

```
db.ds_dashboards.find({"segments.tagBindings.id": 
    {$all:[ObjectId("54ac12f4b4f22ec30153ea83"), ObjectId("54999a0e899ab5530031535e")]},
 "segments.tagBindings": { $size: 2  }})
```

Comment: $all and $size will not help there, because I don't know amount of matched items. If document has only one item (`"id" : ObjectId("54ac12f4b4f22ec30153ea83")`), it should be returned.  Query should return documents with any number of selected Id.

Comment: I assume this query will be built dynamically so you can adjust the matching array and $size accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I will build query dynamically. But I don't know what is amount of matched Id in records. For example, I can use array with 15 Id in query  and even if some record has only 4 Id from that array, it should be returned.  So, $all can not be used here